# elastic beanstalk wordpress permalinks do not persist

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a WordPress standard site on AWS elastic beanstalk with this tutorial

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hawordpress-tutorial.html

Everything works fine but urls are not working with pretty permalinks... They return a 404. I can go in settings and save, then it works.

But as soon as my instances restart, I have to go back and save again in wp admin settings permalinks.

Comment: do you have a .htaccess file in your app, so on `eb deploy` the .htaccess file will be deployed to app on instance initialisation?

Comment: if you don't have a .htaccess file visit this link to have an idea about the content of the file: https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess  and include it in your app.  If this will resolve the issue I will post it as an answer